# Command Button in Visualforce Page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am using the following lines of code in my VF page to open the URL & it's opening in the same tab but I need to open a new Tab as soon as clicking the custom URL Button?

**<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.My_Obj__c.My_custom_link)}" value="My custom button"/>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I have ever seen a button that opens something as new tab/window? Link yes, but not button. Think if that's really what you want, user might be surprised with unexpected behaviour.

Try using [`<apex:commandLink action="{!URLFOR($Action.My_Obj__c.My_custom_link)} target="_blank">`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm). You could [style it to look like button](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000973iIAA) by looking at class names (both in Classic and Lightning Experience).

If that doesn't work - worst case you can always capture `onclick` and do `window.open` or whatever from there...